# Apply multiple conditions to single column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

| Code | count | AA | BB | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | No | NO | 4 |
| 101 | 2 | Yes | NO | 5 |
| 101 | 3 | Yes | NO | 10 |
| 102 | 1 | Yes | NO | 7 |
| 102 | 2 | Yes | NO | 40 |
| 102 | 3 | Yes | NO | 6 |
| 102 | 4 | No | NO | 12 |

I want to apply the condition as,

- If the `count` column is 1 with respect to `code` column then `AA` should be `"NO"` and `BB` should be `"NO"`.
- For `count` between the max and min `count` with respect to `code` column then `AA` can be `"NO"` or `"YES"` and `BB` should be `"NO"`.
- For the max `count` column with respect to `code` column then `AA` should be `"NO"` and `BB` should be `"NO"`.

| Code | count | AA | BB | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | No | NO | 4 |
| 101 | 2 | Yes | NO | 5 |
| 102 | 2 | Yes | NO | 40 |
| 102 | 3 | Yes | NO | 6 |
| 102 | 4 | No | NO | 12 |

Hi,@Darren Tsai Whatever might be the case if the count column is 1 then it is getting deleted completely, by using you code I am getting the below output

| Code | count | AA | BB | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 | Yes | NO | 5 |
| 102 | 2 | Yes | NO | 40 |
| 102 | 3 | Yes | NO | 6 |
| 102 | 4 | No | NO | 12 |

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(data)` for me? It's hard to find the problem out without your real data.

Comment: Hi @DarrenTsai Can you check it near question only I have added the output which I am getting.I think you haven't considered any condition when count is 1 as it is not capturing any data of count 1 irrespective of AA & BB. It should capture for count 1 whenever AA & BB are NO only

Comment: I have considered the min and max counts in `count %in% range(count)` part of my code. I update a reproducible data in my post. Please use it and run my code again. It gets the correct output.

Comment: @DarrenTsai No I am getting it wrong

Comment: I have copied R as you said but I am getting a wrong output

Comment: Why not sharing your data to me? Run `dput(your_data)` and give me what you see.

Comment: structure(list(Unique_Id = c(8540, 8540, 2254, 2254, 607, 607, 
607, 607, 607, 607, 607, 607), AA = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), count = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), BB = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))  @DarrenTsai added data

Comment: This dataset has 12 rows with 3 ID `8540`, `2254`, `607`. After running my code the 2nd, 4th, 12th rows are removed, right? Is this what you want?

Comment: Correct 2nd, 4th, 12th are removed

Comment: But this dataset is different from that in your question. You should give me `dput()` of the original dataset, i.e. ID `101` and `102`.

Comment: This is also same dataset, only ID is different. I have nearly 4k rows of dataset. Can you write the code for the above data which I have provided now

Comment: Whatever the data, my code works for all ID. See my updates.

Comment: I got it now, thank you. But I have a question 'NO' why we are using uppercase here ?

Comment: I'm just worried that there are arbitrary "NO", "No", and "no" in `AA` and `BB`, so I turn the whole column into uppercase. If you're sure the case styles are consistent, you can skip `toupper()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(flag = count %in% range(count)) %>%
  filter(flag & if_all(c(AA, BB), ~ toupper(.x) == 'NO') | !flag & toupper(BB) == 'NO') %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-flag)

# # A tibble: 5 × 5
#    Code count AA    BB       CC
#   <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1   101     1 No    NO        4
# 2   101     2 Yes   NO        5
# 3   102     2 Yes   NO       40
# 4   102     3 Yes   NO        6
# 5   102     4 No    NO       12
```

---

A `base` equivalent:

```r
df |>
  transform(flag = ave(count, Code, FUN = \(x) x %in% range(x))) |>
  subset(flag & toupper(AA) == 'NO' & toupper(BB) == 'NO' | !flag & toupper(BB) == 'NO', -flag)
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Code = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L),
count = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), AA = c("No", "Yes",
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), BB = c("NO", "NO", "NO", "NO",
"NO", "NO", "NO"), CC = c(4L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 40L, 6L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-7L))
```

---

#### Update with another dataset

This dataset has 12 rows with 3 ID `8540`, `2254`, `607`. After running my code the 2nd, 4th, 12th rows are removed.

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 <- structure(list(Unique_Id = c(8540, 8540, 2254, 2254, 607, 607, 607, 607, 607, 607, 607, 607),
                      AA = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"),
                      count = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                      BB = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes")),
                      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df2
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   Unique_Id AA    count BB
       <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1      8540 No        1 No
 2      8540 Yes       2 Yes
 3      2254 No        1 No
 4      2254 No        2 Yes
 5       607 No        1 No
 6       607 No        2 No   
 7       607 No        3 No
 8       607 No        4 No
 9       607 No        5 No
10       607 No        6 No
11       607 No        7 No
12       607 No        8 Yes

df2 %>%
  group_by(Unique_Id) %>%
  mutate(flag = count %in% range(count)) %>%
  filter(flag & if_all(c(AA, BB), ~ toupper(.x) == 'NO') | !flag & toupper(BB) == 'NO') %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-flag)

# A tibble: 9 × 4
  Unique_Id AA    count BB
      <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1      8540 No        1 No
2      2254 No        1 No
3       607 No        1 No
4       607 No        2 No
5       607 No        3 No
6       607 No        4 No
7       607 No        5 No
8       607 No        6 No   
9       607 No        7 No
```